# Передача значений в функцию и ООП в python

Tags: python, ооп, разработка-игр

Я потихоньку пилю текстовую игру и столкнулся с проблемой универсальности. Не знаю как изложить суть более грамотно, но вот в чем фишка: существует внутри игры дочерний класс врага Enemy, который является универсальным и без особого труда редактируется в нужный момент.

```
class Enemy(Player):
    def __init__(self, enemy_name, hp, damage, dex, mp):
        super().__init__(enemy_name, hp, damage, dex, mp)
    def spawn(self):
        enemy_loot = ['']
        return enemy_loot
```

Далее встает задача создать функцию вызова битвы с ними, которая тоже будет построена по универсальному шаблону

```
def battle_state():
    enemy = Goblin
    print('Дикое существо', enemy.player_class, 'напало на вас')
    print('У вас есть несколько опций...')
    while enemy.hp > 0:
        choice = input('1 - удар мечом\n2 - использовать магию\n3 - убежать\n')

        if choice == '1':
            print('С резким лязгом клинка вы атакуете', enemy.player_class)
            hit_chance = random.randint(0,10)
            if hit_chance > 3:
                enemy.hp = enemy.hp - character.damage
                print('Ваш удар достиг цели,здоровье цели равно', enemy.hp)
                if enemy.hp > 0:
                    hit_chance = random.randint(0,10)
                    if hit_chance > 6:
                        character.hp = character.hp - enemy.damage
                        print('Существо атакует в ответ и попадает, у вас осталось', character.hp )
                    else:
                        print('Существо с своей старанием пыталось попасть по вам, но не смогло')
                if enemy.hp <= 0:
                    print('Поздравляю, вы уничтожили своего врага')
            else:
                print('Похоже вы промахнулись')
                if enemy.hp > 0:
                    hit_chance = random.randint(0,10)
                    if hit_chance > 6:
                        character.hp = character.hp - enemy.damage
                        print('Существо атакует в ответ и попадает, у вас осталось', character.hp )
                    else:
                        print('Существо со всем старанием пыталось попасть по вам, но не может')
        if choice == '2':
            print('Призывая магическую энергию, вы пуляете заклинание в ', enemy.player_class)
            hit_chance = random.randint(0, 10)
            if hit_chance > 3:
                enemy.hp = enemy.hp - character.mp
                print('Магия поразила цель, ее здоровье равно', enemy.hp)
                if enemy.hp > 0:
                    hit_chance = random.randint(0, 10)
                    if hit_chance > 6:
                        character.hp = character.hp - enemy.damage
                        print('Существо атакует в ответ и попадает, у вас осталось', character.hp)
                    else:
                        print('Существо с всем старанием пыталось попасть по вам, но не смогло')
                if enemy.hp <= 0:
                    print('Поздравляю, вы уничтожили своего врага')
            else:
                print('Похоже вы промахнулись')
                if enemy.hp > 0:
                    hit_chance = random.randint(0, 10)
                    if hit_chance > 6:
                        character.hp = character.hp - enemy.damage
                        print('Существо атакует в ответ и попадает, у вас осталось', character.hp)
                    else:
                        print('Существо со всем старанием пыталось попасть по вам, но не может')
```

Т.е. создав такую функцию однажды, мы можем вызывать теперь ее тогда, когда нам по внутри игровому событию нужна битва. Однако, как мне всякий раз передавать ей значение разных врагов? Конкретно в моем случае я прописал enemy = Goblin, взятое из глобальной переменной. Я так думаю, всякий раз перед вызовом функции не вариант создавать очередную глобальную переменную для врага. И уж тем более непонятно что делать, если врагов несколько

Так вот, как это исправить? Как вообще называется то, что я пытаюсь сделать? Буду очень рад, если вы укажете мне в каком направлении идти читать информацию, а то я совсем запутался

Comment: перенесите эту функцию в класс гейм или батл .и оттуда создавайте объекты врагов и бой.

Comment: Хороший совет, это помогло. Спасибо вам

Answer (score 2):

Хочу начать с того, что ты не сосем верно уловил суть полиморфизма, НЕ нужно наследовать врага от игрока ибо это разные сущности. Тем самым "универсальным классом" был бы класс Enemy скажем, ведь у каждого врага есть HP, MP, и прочие характеристики а вот особенность каждого отдельного врага можно сделать, создав дочерние классы, например по такому виду Goblin(Enemy), GiantBat(Enemy) и т.д. таким образом в методах дочерних классов, ты можешь добавить уникальность поведения твоих врагов. Но, это может усложнить тебе жизнь, если ты еще не до конца продумал все детали своей игры(сначала она должна быть создана "на бумаге", тогда ты будешь знать что делать), поэтому сделай отдельный класс Enemy, для начала. В него добавь методы всех твоих будущих врагов, например гоблин делает порез, мышь укус и т.д. а в игре врагов будешь отличать создавая экземпляры класса Enemy в соответствующих переменных

```
goblin = Enemy(hp = 50, mp = 0, magic = False) 
monster_bat = Enemy(hp = 30, mp = 5, magic = True)
```

Теперь про бой, я не вдавался в подробности твоего кода, но суть ты уловил if, else и random на вероятность ударов. имея переменные с экземплярами классов, ты легко можешь манипулировать данными в них:

```
if hit:
    goblin.hp - 5
    player.hp + 1 #вампиризм, а кто сказал что нельзя?)
```

а вот сама схема придумывается тобой, это и придает уникальность в каждую игру. реши как они будут выбивать дурь из друг друга и реализуй это используя приемы программирования. Поэтому сложно тебе будет что-то сказать, не придумывая ее за тебя) хороший художник рисует картину, а гениальный ворует идею хорошего художника. Попробуй скопировать механику боя известной тебе игры.

Comment: Гуд, спасибо за совет! Буду пробовать

Comment: насчёт врага и игрока...обычно они идут от персон